# How to check if Kafka Broker is alive?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-boot-actuator

How to check if Kafka Brocker is alive?

I have SpringBoot aplication and use '@KafkaListener' to consume messages.
I want to create custom healthceck for kafka brocker, but i can't use KafkaAdmin (by permissoin questions). How to check if Kafka Broker (or is conusumer connect to broker) is alive by other way?